# How to get coordinates from a location name

Tags: android, location, coordinates

In my app user types a location and I have to get latitude and longitude for that location. So here I don't have `Location` object but a `String`.

I thought of an option to create a `Location` object using this `String` but it is not possible.

I know using Google's places API it is possible and I know how to use that, but I prefer using any method available in SDK.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one possibilty(other than Google geocode API) to get latitude and longitude as stated by yakiv.mospan. But `Geocoder` always returns me `null` and so is the case for many people. This I come to know by searching this issue of returning null on stackoverflow.com.

After all, I decided to use [Google places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/)  as there is no other option available.

Comment: It's paid after some requests

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html). Like this :

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(App.getContext(), Locale.US);
    List<Address> listOfAddress;
    try {
        listOfAddress = geocoder.getFromLocation(theLatitude, theLongitude, 1);
        if(listOfAddress != null && !listOfAddress.isEmpty()){
        Address address = listOfAddress.get(0);

        String country = address.getCountryCode();
        String adminArea= address.getAdminArea();
        String locality= address.getLocality();

    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Updated :** to get location from address use :

```
listOfAddress = geocoder.getFromLocationName("Address", 1);
```

and to get lat, lon :

```
double latitude = address.getLatitude();
double longitude = address.getLongitude();
```

**Updated :** using this snippet to get Location when Geocoder returns null:

```
private static final String URL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml";

public static RemoteCommand getLocation(String theAddress){
    RemoteCommand result = new RemoteCommand();

    result.setType(Type.GET);
    result.setUrl(URL);
    result.addGetParam("address", theAddress);
    result.addGetParam("sensor", "false");
    result.addGetParam("language", "en");

    // See description about GeocoderXMLHandler
    result.setXmlHandler(new GeocoderXMLHandler());

    return result;
}
```

Best wishes.

Comment: How accurate is this that first address in the list will be address of location name?

Comment: And you always can get all information from Address and check it.

Comment: This did not work. `geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationString, 1);` always returns null. I saw many question about getting null always and finally they got rid of it and used Google API.

Comment: It returns null not always and only in Android 4+. Usually reboot fix this issue. But u are right, I am always handling if it is null and use Geocoder API when it is. Updated answer. Pleas mark answer as accepted if it was right.

Comment: have you tried geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationString, 5); and iterate through response, if 1st one is null

Answer (score 3):

```
String UrlCity = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + NameString + "&sensor=false";

        JsonObjectRequest stateReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, UrlState, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                JSONObject location;
                try {
                    // Get JSON Array called "results" and then get the 0th
                    // complete object as JSON
                    location = response.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");
                    // Get the value of the attribute whose name is
                    // "formatted_string"
                    stateLocation = new LatLng(location.getDouble("lat"), location.getDouble("lng"));
                    // System.out.println(stateLocation.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();

                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
            }
        });
        // add it to the RequestQueue
        reqQueue.add(stateReq);
```

you get coordinates from given name. This is done by using [Google Volley library](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728), or you can do it by a simple http call wrapped in AsyncTask or runnable.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

The getFromLocationName method can help you.

Comment: I want to get coordinates, not address or location name.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Geocoding API to get coordinates for an address. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding

In this detail infromation on how to use is given. 
Also below is sample URL so check response and see whether this is useful for you or not.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ahmedabad&sensor=false

Comment: First of all, the first link you sent is for javascript? Have I mentioned javascript anywhere? And in my question I sad I know about this API. At least read the question completely.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use this code:

```
String add = address + "," + city + "," + country;

String addressUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
                + URLEncoder.encode(add.replaceAll(" ", "+"))
                + "&sensor=true";
try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();// Client

            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet();
            getRequest.setURI(new URI(addressUrl));

            // HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost();
            // postRequest.setURI(new URI(url));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
                    .getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();
            String page = sb.toString();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(page);
            if (jsonObject.has("results")) {
                JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results");

                if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                    jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(0);
                    if (jsonObject.has("geometry")) {
                        jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonObject
                                .get("geometry");

                        if (jsonObject.has("location")) {
                            JSONObject location = (JSONObject) jsonObject
                                    .get("location");

                            latitude = (Double) location.get("lat");
                            longitude = (Double) location.get("lng");
                            Log.e(TAG, "lat : " + latitude + " long : "
                                    + longitude);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Here are more links that can help you:

[Google Map V2](http://karnshah8890.blogspot.in/2013/02/google-maps-android-api-v2.html)

[Google Places API Demo](http://karnshah8890.blogspot.in/2013/03/google-places-api-tutorial.html)

Answer (score -1):

you can use this,

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 3);
```